# Selecting from a table based on relationships which are saved in another table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

### My Situation

I am using SQLite on Android to store some data. This data is all in the same table, but each row can have one or more relationships to other rows in that same table. These relationships are saved in another table. Think of it like this:

In Table 1 may be a row with id 0 which has 2 children with the ids 1 and 2. Both of those children will again be saved in table 1, but in table 2 there will be a mapping for each of those children from the id 0 to their own id. The tables may look something like this:

```
+---------------------------+     
|           Table 1         |     
+------+------+------+------+     
|  ID  |   .... Data ....   |     
+------+------+------+------+     
|  0   | ...  | ...  | ...  |   <--- This would be the parent of rows 1 & 2         
|  1   | ...  | ...  | ...  |        as indicated in the other table
|  2   | ...  | ...  | ...  |      
|  3   | ...  | ...  | ...  |     

+----------------------------+
|           Table 2          | 
+-------------+--------------+
|  Parent ID  |   Child ID   |
|      0      |       1      |   <-- This means that row 0 has
|      0      |       2      |   <-- 2 children with the ids 1 and 2  
|      2      |       5      |          
|      3      |       2      |   <-- Each row can have multiple parents and/or children
```

What I want to do essentially is select from table 1 with some arbitrary where clause and if this where clause for example matches row 0, I also need to select the children of row 0 along with it and the children of those children and so on. Since I generally suck at explaining things let me illustrate this again:

If I were to run a `select` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ...
```

I would get a result like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+     
|  ID  |   .... Data ....   |     
+------+------+------+------+     
|  0   | ...  | ...  | ...  |      
|  3   | ...  | ...  | ...  |
```

But what I would like to get is this:

```
+------+---------+------+------+------+     
|  ID  | isChild |   .... Data ....   |     
+------+---------+------+------+------+     
|  0   |    0    | ...  | ...  | ...  |   <--- This row along with row 3 is what actually matches the where clause            
|  1   |    1    | ...  | ...  | ...  |
|  2   |    1    | ...  | ...  | ...  |      
|  5   |    2    | ...  | ...  | ...  |
|  3   |    0    | ...  | ...  | ...  |   <--- This row along with row 0 is what actually matches the where clause            
|  2   |    1    | ...  | ...  | ...  |
|  5   |    2    | ...  | ...  | ...  |
```

Only row 1 and 3 actually match the where clause. The order of the children is not important but they should follow right after the parent and the "isChild" column would be used to indicate whether the row is a child and to what it is a child.

Notice the third row from the top in the output above, the one with the id 2. It has `2` in "isChild" because it is a child of the row above which also is a child. You can think of the whole output above as a tree like this:

```
- 0 
   - 1      <-- 1 is a child of 0
   - 2      <-- 2 is a child of 0
      - 5   <-- 5 is a child of 2
- 3
   - 2      <-- 2 is a child of 3
      - 5   <-- 5 is a child of 2
```

The "isChild" column essentially tells you on which level of the tree you are.

---

### The Problem

Up until now I had implemented this with multiple `selects`. I would first select the rows from table1, take the ids from each row and then select the mappings for each row from table2. With those mappings I would select the children from table1 and after that I would again look for mappings of the children in table2 and so on. It doesn't take a genius to see that this can cause huge performance problems very quickly and it indeed was pretty slow.

I have since then been trying to improve this by reducing the number of `selects` required but now I have hit a wall. I have implemented any sort of improvement I can think of and it works for the most part but if you are dealing with big datasets everything slows down exponentially and I don't see any other way I could improve this in code. I started thinking and came to the conclusion that if I could somehow select everything at once in the manner I described above it would solve a whole slew of problems for me.

---

### My attempts to solve the problem so far

Since I cannot improve this further in code I have turned my attention to SQL. I have already made many unrelated improvements which resulted in great performance gains by implementing triggers to do the most common tasks like creating and deleting the mappings in table2. And I have been hoping I can also solve this problem in a similar manner.

I have tried all sorts of `JOIN`s or `UNION`s but nothing seems to work as I expect it. I have a feeling I might be going about this all the wrong way. I haven't event attempted to include a "isChild" column up until now.

[**This is a link to the SQLFiddle I use to test my selects**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54961b)

When I started working on this I foolishly thought that a simple `JOIN` would solve the problem but I am doubting that at this point and I am also not sure if what I want to do is even possible (in an efficient manner).

---

This problem has made me realise how little I know about SQL and if some SQL wizard could come along and tell me how simple the solution actually is I would very much appreciate it! (Although I suspect that the solution to my problem isn't actually that simple)

**Please keep in mind that this question is talking specifically about SQLite on Android. But I tried to make this question as general as possible since it is also applicable for many other SQL implementations or operating systems.**

<sub>If you have a really great answer to this question with a simple solution that blows my mind and a great explanation to go along with then I won't hesitate to reward you with a bounty.</sub>

Comment: this might help http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/

Comment: @FuzzyTree Very clever, but this article is assuming that each row can only have one parent, which isn't true in my case. I already have a few ideas how I can modify this to make it work in my situation but feel free to write an answer if you can think of a way faster than I can.

Comment: it sounds like you want to save a graph (because trees don't allow children to have multiple parents). i don't see an obvious way to modify that algorithm to save graphs because the left and right values of a parent are determined by the left and right values of its children

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I have a many-to-many relationship between rows in the same table, the second table I have contains those "links" you are talking about. It specifies which rows are children of other rows. And that part is working perfectly, the problem I have is how I can select rows from the first table together with all their children and the children of those children in one single select like I describe in my question.

Comment: @FuzzyTree I think you can actually modify it, but you need to calculate a different set of values for each and every parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read the children recursively, you would have to use a [recursive common table expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html#recursivecte).

However, this was introduced in SQLite 3.8.3, so your Android device is very unlikely to support it.

You have to keep using multiple queries, or to use your own version of SQLite with the NDK.